# Accessing elements inside Array elements in scala

Tags: scala, tuples

In scala, I know you can access the n'th element in an Array with
`Array(n)`, for example `z(1) = (3, 4)` for the array z:

```
z: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,4), (6,7), (8,9))
```

But how do I acsess the first element in the second element (which would be 3)?

Answer (score 5):

`(3, 4)` is of type [Tuple2](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html).

You can access its first element via:

```
val first = z(1)._1
```

or:

```
val (first, _) = z(1)
```